# Phantom JS load url from local file or string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phantomjs

I need to run Phantomjs not on a URL but on a local saved page that's not hosted on the web just exists in a txt file, or a string, and then I need to return an array of images:  So I have two questions.

**my PHP function:**

`$result = shell_exec('phantomjs myscript.js');`

1. Can I return an array or do i simply do `console.log(array[i])`;
2. How do I inject html into `page.open` or how can I load a local page?

## myscript.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.viewportSize = { width: 320, height: 480 };
    page.open('somelocalpage.php', function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to access the network!');
        } else {
            page.evaluate(function () {
               //find all images:
               //return array.

            });


        }
        phantom.exit();
    });
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more Q1 please ? ^^ (for Q2 idk)

Comment: Try `page.open('file:///somelocalpage.php', function (status) {`, also it wont parse php within that file.

Comment: @lozCherone that file has no PHP just HTML and Javascript

Comment: When I do that I get Unable to access the network

Comment: ..also something like this would be done much much easyier with DOMDocument or such parser.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot get the complete data with a CURL as some of it is created with Javascript.

Comment: Are you sure you used the file URI correctly? See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) and it must be absolute.